# How to install kodi on Raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I tryed many tutorial, but can't install kodi.
I get 3 running process "kodi" by "top" command, but have no kodi interface on Raspbian desktop.
Please help me how to do that.

Comment: Which tutorials have you tried?  What version of Raspbian are you using?  How did you install Kodi?

Answer (score 0):

try to type

> kodi-standalone

you can [see](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=99866):

> sudo nano /usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to run Kodi on Raspbian and not installing LibreElec (which is built for running Kodi ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kodi -y
```

If you already installed Kodi then replace install for reinstall.